# ModuleNotFoundError: cart.contexts with django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I use Python3 and Django 1.11

```py
def add_to_cart(request, id):
    """Add a quantity of the specified product to the cart"""
    quantity=int(request.POST.get('quantity'))

    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    if id in cart:
        cart[id] = int(cart[id]) + quantity      
    else:
        cart[id] = cart.get(id, quantity)

    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect(reverse('index'))
```

> ModuleNotFoundError --- Exception Value: No module named 'cart.contexts'

Comment: I am student the project is python3 django 1.11 ( i have to run 1.11 because course requires that version)

Comment: Does it tell you where that error is coming from?  It doesn't look like it would be from the code you have included.

Comment: hey Mark I solved the problem myself. You're correct it was syntax error in related file.

Comment: Mark, I have other issue to resolve that you might be able to help with. It is not a bug but some functionality I wish to implement in my project and am not sure how to address the matter. If interested reach me at gmail. My email address is my stack overflow profile name @... cheers, john